# My Multi item carousel is collapsing while on resizing the screen size(Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Try to adjust the output screen, the carousel will collapse and the last few items will come under and then they will disappear. My need is carousel not to collapse when resizing it.

Please Help Me!

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/AK96/pen/dgzMgB)

```js
ResCarouselSize();

$(window).resize(function () {
  ResCarouselSize();
});

//this function define the size of the items
function ResCarouselSize() {
  var incno = 0;
  var dataItems = ("data-items");
  var itemClass = ('.item');
  var id = 0;
  var btnParentSb = '';
  var itemsSplit = '';
  var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
  var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
  $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
    id = id + 1;
    var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
    btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
    itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
    $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);

    if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
      incno = itemsSplit[3];
      itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
    }
    else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
      incno = itemsSplit[2];
      itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
    }
    else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
      incno = itemsSplit[1];
      itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
    }
    else {
      incno = itemsSplit[0];
      itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
    }
    $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
    $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
      $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
    });

    $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
    $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try commenting this... 
//ResCarouselSize();

Comment: it wont work! @BuggyParadox you can see my code pen link above

Comment: I hope you tried it...

Comment: Already tried it!

Comment: Perhaps, instead of hard-binding the widths, you can use HTML-5 screen responsiveness solution, which is inbuilt. See: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.MultiCarousel{ Height: 185px;}** this will fix your problem